# Two ways to select ranges in SQL, only one in MongoDB?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, mongodb, syntax

I have the following SELECT statement for SQL.

```
SELECT TransAmount FROM STOCK WHERE TransAmount between 100 and 110;
```

However, this statement generates an error from querymongo.com. It says "Failure parsing MySQL query: Unable to parse WHERE clause due to unrecognized operator ". I assume it is talking about the between clause.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but does this SQL statement do the exact same thing as the one above?

```
SELECT TransAmount FROM STOCK WHERE TransAmount > 100 and TransAmount < 110;
```

This statement generates the following MongoDB code.

```
db.STOCK.find({
    "TransAmount": {
        "$gt": 100,
        "$lt": 110
    }
}, {
    "TransAmount": 1
});
```

It looks like MongoDB doesn't have a 'between' operator. Does MongoDB handle selection within ranges with a different keyword, or do you have to set it up like so $gt/%lt?

Comment: your 2 statements are identical...

Comment: Raw SQL does not translate well to solutions such as MongoDB. What is it you actually want to do? How is your data currently structured? The reasons for using a NoSQL solution usually mean doing things differently to how you did them before. Otherwise there is no point.

Comment: I think your first statement should be `SELECT TransAmount FROM STOCK WHERE TransAmount BETWEEN 100 AND 110`;

Comment: querymongo.com may not have intelligence to generate between of mongodb

Comment: fixed the duplicate sql statements. I'm converting batches of SQL queries into MongoDB queries so we can stress test some software.

Comment: Between is just a shortcut of what your doing in the second query, a non-standard one at that

Comment: @Sammaye, so does Mongo handle ranges in a way different from the example mongo query?

Comment: No that is the one and only way, well unless you count $in etc but those are different kinds of ranges to what you mean

Comment: cool. you want to post that as an answer and get some fake internet points?

Comment: Ok since it allows you to close the question

Comment: @Sammaye can you explain what you mean by "a non-standard one at that"?  In ANSI-92 BETWEEN is defined and its behavior is defined as `"X BETWEEN Y AND Z" is equivalent to "X>=Y AND X<=Z"` which is by the way subtly different from what you state.

Comment: @fvu Ah ok so it is actually standard that it is inclusive, fair enioguh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between is just a shortcut (a sort of symlink) to your second query, I guess it makes life easier.

MongoDB has not yet implemented such a shortcut, I have looked around a bit for a JIRA declaring someone wants such an operator however, no luck.

The one and only way of doing ranges in MongoDB is to use `$gt` and `$lt` (you could count `$in` etc but that is a different kind of range, not what your looking for).